# Top and side navigation bars

Tags: website-design, navigation, mobile-web

Here is our website user interface for desktop and mobile devices.

Basically, what we wanted to achieve on desktop, is to give visitors the ability to easily browse among all the purchase related pages through the right side navigation bar.

The questions now are: from the UX standards point of view, should we repeat the 'Buy' link in two places with different name `(1)Buy` & `(2)Buy now`? Should we repeat them with the same name instead? Should we omit the `(2)Buy now` label and force visitors to go back to top navigation bar to see the initial page? What about the mobile version instead?

Thanks.

Desktop:

[image]

Phone:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Particularly in your case, there are 'Buy' links repetitive on the same(side by side) places, which do not add any value to the user experience.

Having navigational repeated links are fine, but one should be careful during designing hierarchy of it. For example, after scrolling down, if the 'Buy' from navigation bar will be gone then you can provide another CTA(call-to-action) 'Buy now' link. So, here I think the Buy now under Buy doesn't add the value and increase the efforts(clicks).

Please refer this link for a detailed explanation: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/duplicate-links/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this short answer will be helpful. This topic could be debated at length I'm sure!

It is not considered bad practice to repeat a call to action, but this seems a little odd that both are within navigational elements.

Top nav / header positioning it good - consistent point of reference.

I would suggest making any secondary 'buy' call to actions sit in context within the page content. Hopefully the content will be compelling, the user will read through, scroll down - so you want to make sure you get your buy options in their field of view.

Comment: what do you mean with 'sit in context within the page content' exactly?

Comment: Where there is a more direct call to action following a piece of text, describing the offering.

Comment: This does not answer the question, sorry. I'm looking for a solution on if and where to duplicate the top navigation item.